# ERC721, Token name and symbol not shown in etherscan

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, erc-721

I have created a simple token with ERC721, but etherscan not show my token name and symbol, why? this is my contract

[image]

I deploy with this code

[image]

Result on etherscan 
[image]

No token name and symbol showed, is there something wrong?

Comment: Have you verified the contract on Etherscan? Also can you please put the transaction link in comment to make it copy-able.

Comment: thank you, my problem has been solved. I made a transaction on a new deployed contract, and the token name was shown. contract link https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x677F76D276355c382Da948d2476DA06cf5dc6219

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. When you do your first token transfer it will automatically be visible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to sending your token info to Etherscan team. You can do this here https://etherscan.io/contactus and as subject select "Update Token Info".

Comment: I think this is only for updating the icon shown on the token's Etherscan page, rather than anything that can be read from the contract directly.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time to be indexed. While the address indexing immediately, additional data can appear minutes later.